# Randomly select and swap two elements of a vector

Tags: arrays, vector

So I had a test and received a comment from my professor that my function was inefficient. The function was supposed to do the following:
-Randomly select 2 elements in the vector and swap their values
-Make sure there is an element to swap though:

I know that there is a swap() function that could normally be used but my professor said we could not #include  (we are in VS). My question is how to make this more efficient. This is more out of curiosity as I still did well on the test, but I can't stand it when I cannot figure something out.

So this is what I made.

```
void IntegerCollection::SwapTwoElements()
{
    if (MyVector.size() >= 1)
    {
        int i;
        int j;
        int holder1;
        int holder2;
        i = rand() % (MyVector.size());
        j = rand() % (MyVector.size());
        holder1 = MyVector[i];
        holder2 = MyVector[j];
        MyVector[j] = holder1;
        MyVector[i] = holder2;
    }

}
```

//the easy way would have been but we were not able to use swap

```
std::swap (MyVector[rand() % (MyVector.size())] , MyVector[rand() % (MyVector.size())]);
```

Thank you to anyone kind enough to help me stop banging my head off the wall trying to figure out another solution.

Comment: Are you sure he was talking about the rand()? Maybe he meant that holder2 is not needed here

Comment: The single swap location is the first improvement.  The instructor may also be referring to the no extra memory swap, which you'd need to first make sure you didn't select the same location. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm

Comment: I found out after getting a change to speak with him that it was because I used holder2 which is unnecessary. Thank you for the help guys. We have not really worked with a no extra memory swap scenario yet (as far as I know), but I'm sure that will be coming down the pipe. Thank you both.

Comment: Additionally I want to mark your answer as correct Shahar but I don't seem to have anything to click on to allow me to register your answer as the correct solution. Either way, you guys are both great and I appreciate your effort.